# Почему могут не работать col-md, col-lg?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

а работают лить offset, push. В чем ошибка? Если указать col-md-2, то вообще съезжают на другой блок. Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Третья версия бутстрапа, до этого col-md и остальное работало в этом файле.

```
  <section class="black-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: какой бутстрап подключаете, почему пример не сделаете воспроизводимым, на какой ширине эркрана смотрите??? дополните вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Вот воспроизводимый пример:

```css
p {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="black-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ваш код работает абсолютно корректно.
 Причина ошибки может быть в том, что вы где-то предопределили стиль или не подключили стиль бутстрапа или не знаете на какой ширине экрана смотреть эту ширину колонки.
 Гадать без реально воспроизводимой ошибки можно бесконечно. Посмотрите с помощью дев тулс какие стили определяет браузер в этом диве.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в head это, возможно поможет:

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```